# in Clojure, is a vector a specific hashmap?

Tags: clojure

On "Programming Clojure", there is an example using get function on a vector:

```
(get [:a :b :c] 1)
-> :b
```

I called (doc get) and it looks like get function takes hashmap as argument but not vector, so I wander if vector is some kind of hashmap. I remember a hashmap can take an index integer, and return value matching that index, so I did this to see if vector can do same thing:

```
([1 2 3 4] 1)
-> 2
```

It did return value 2, which is at index 1 in [1 2 3 4].

Does this mean a vector is a hashmap, whose keys-value pair is index-value pair?

Comment: mathematically speaking, a vector is a *map* - a function (a mathematic function). I don't know how it is implemented in clojure specifically, but I doubt it is implemented using a hash. clojure is dynamically typed, so it doesn't care what is the actual type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the underlying implementation is different.

That being said, since logically vectors do map indices to elements, they are associative structures in Clojure and can be used with `get`, `contains?` and `assoc` (though for `assoc` only indices from 0 to 1 past the end of the vector can be used). They cannot be used with `dissoc` though -- that's a "real map" operation.

Also, vectors act differently to maps when used as functions: calling a map as a function is equivalent to using it with `get`, while calling a vector is equivalent to using `nth`. The difference is that `nth` throws an exception on index-out-of-bounds (as well as arguments which could not possibly be indices, such as negative numbers or non-numbers), whereas `get` returns `nil`.